# Reshape wide to long, multiple columns and multiple time periods

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape

I'm trying to reshape data from wide to long and I cant get the answer. The structure is as follows:

| id | n_dep_1 | n_dep_2 | bleed_1 | bleed_2 | secretion_1 | secretion_2 | eva_1 | eva_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 9 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 7 | 5 |

note: i have 14 measurements of every key variable "n_dep","bleed","secretion" and "eva".

I need something like this:

| id | n_dep | bleed | secretion | eva |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 6 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 7 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 5 |

I tried this:

```
require(data.table)
melt(setDT(data_wide), id="id",
     measure=patterns("n_dep_$", "eva_$", "bleed_$","secretion_$"), 
     value.name=c("n_dep", "eva", "bleed","secretion"))
```

and I got this error:

> Error in do_patterns(measure.sub, names(data)) :
> Patterns not found: [n_dep_$, eva_$, bleed_$, secretion_$]

I also tried with reshape and gather, and I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not data.table, but with the tidyverse you can do this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
d |> 
  gather("var", "val", -id) |> 
  mutate(id2 = str_extract(var, "\\d$"), 
         var = str_remove(var, "_\\d$")) |> 
  spread(var, val)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>      id id2   bleed   eva n_dep secretion
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1 1         1     9     1         1
#> 2     1 2         1     7     2         1
#> 3     2 1         0     5     2         1
#> 4     2 2         1     6     1         0
#> 5     3 1         1     7     2         1
#> 6     3 2         0     5     1         1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this is with a single call to `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`:

```r
tidyr::pivot_longer(data_wide, -id, names_pattern = '(^.*)_', names_to = ".value") 

#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>      id n_dep bleed secretion   eva
#>   <int> <int> <int>     <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     1         1     9
#> 2     1     2     1         1     7
#> 3     2     2     0         1     5
#> 4     2     1     1         0     6
#> 5     3     2     1         1     7
#> 6     3     1     0         1     5
```

Answer (score 0):

The regexp in the patterns does not match the column names.

You've currently specified as follows, with, for example "n_dep_$" presumably expecting to match n_dep_1, n_dep_2, etc.  The regexp is asking for column names that end in an underscore and have no number after, as the $ marks the end of the input.

do_patterns is returning the error because the regexp isn't matched in the column names.

Try instead:

```
melt(setDT(data_wide), id="id",
     measure=patterns("^n_dep_\\d+$", "^eva_\\d+$", "^bleed_\\d+$","^secretion_\\d+$"), 
     value.name=c("n_dep", "eva", "bleed","secretion"))
```

This ^ notes the start of the input, and $ the end of the input.  So here, `^n_dep_\\d+$` requests columns that begin with "n_dep_" and end in one (or more) digits.